# Perfomance Displaying Record In Single Page Application Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want displaying data from some model on one view. I'm build one page site.

```
def index
 @content = Content.where(:publish => true)
 @myaccount = Myaccount.where(:publish => true)
 @sliders = Slider.where(:publish => true)
end
```

[image]

I know, I can display them following like this:

```
<div class="left">
 <div>
  <% @myaccounts.each do |ma|  %>
   <%= ma.name %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
 <div>
  <% @contents.each do |co| %>
   <%= co.menu %>
  <% end %>
 <div>
</div>
<div class="right">
 <div>
  <% @myaccounts.each do |mac|  %>
   <%= mac.title %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
 <div>
  <% @sliders.each do |sl|  %>
   <%= image_tag(sl.image_url) %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
 <div>
  <% @contents.each do |con|  %>
   <%= con.body %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

Time

```
Completed 200 OK in 4679ms (Views: 1515.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2601.2ms)
```

If use `<%= render 'file' %>` , Time :

```
Completed 200 OK in 2673ms (Views: 2652.2ms | ActiveRecord: 18.0ms)
```

Is the correct way to display record on rails? If yes, is there a simple structure way to get them?

Answer (score 1):

you could use partial for each model like,

**show.erb.html**

```
<div> render :partial => "my_accounts", :locals=>{myaccounts => @myaccounts}</div>
```

and in  **_my_accounts.erb.html**

```
<div>
  <% @myaccounts.each do |ma|  %>
    <%= ma.name %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

but your code will work fine, using partial will make it a bit cleaner.

Comment: so use some file and render with partial is a bit cleaner instead call activerecord in one file?

Comment: In your case yes, it will be easier to handle your code in future.